# How to increase limit of broadcast joining of pyspark from some m.b to G.B

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

First let me tell you what my approach here is:-

I wrote spark applications in `aws glue` bout a month ago and moved it to prod and was working fine till last week.

**Below are my steps**:

1. Renamed column
2. add additions of columns
3. used cached()
4. Joined two `dataframe` using broadcast joining. So the small table was < 1 g.b and I was getting atleast of 1 mins of faster performance of each joining. I'd more than 21 tables. So using broadcasting and caching lots of improvement.

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter","|").csv("s3://test-bucket//2017_2019_workers.csv")

df1 = spark.read.option("delimiter","|").csv("s3://test-bucket//2020_workers.csv")

aggregated_data = df.join(broadcast(df1),df.id == df1.id)
```

But now requirment has changed and since small table is not small anymore and it could increased upto 4 g.b and `aws glue` is failing

```
Spark Error: Total size of serialized results of 268 tasks (1400.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

Now here's my approach of resolving this i considered increasing `spark.driver.maxResultSize = 4g.b`but again job failed.

I considered increasing broadcast `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` but after some time **Glue ETL marketplace cannot iterate over nulls : Exception occured**

Do I need to increase more spark driver memory so that data can spill up across all the nodes.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution?